# Discover if a class has been declared inside a particular module type

Tags: scala, reflection

I am writing a DSL which describes a structure. The DSL uses Types to reference classes which will later be instantiated. I would like to enforce that a particular Type has been declared within a particular module. This can be a runtime check after the DSL has been compiled.

In essence I need to access the outer element starting from the inner class and check it is of the correct type and get a reference to it.

If I get the child type I can get its symbol using reflection by calling to typeSymbol and in the resulting symbol I see that I can call owner to get the outer type symbol. However if I try to reflect the parent as a Module (even when the parent it is a module) it throws an exception.

Lets put an example:

```
trait TheMixin

object TheParent extends TheMixin {
  case class TheChild()
}

object TestDiscoverParent extends App {
  import scala.reflect.runtime.{currentMirror => cm, universe => ru}
  val theChildType = ru.typeOf[TheParent.TheChild]
  val theChildOwner = theChildType.typeSymbol.owner
  println(theChildOwner)
  val theParentModuleSymbol = theChildOwner.asModule
  val theParentRef = cm.reflectModule(theParentModuleSymbol).instance
  println(theParentRef.isInstanceOf[TheMixin])
}
```

In this example, the line `println(theChildOwner)` will print

```
object TheParent
```

But the call to `theChildOwner.asModule` throws an exception:

`Exception in thread "main" scala.ScalaReflectionException: object TheParent is not a module`

How can I get a reference to the outer object wrapper?

Comment: Debugging the code I can see that theClildOwner contains a private field called module which looks like would provide the result I expect. Unfortunately it is private :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to one more indirection, the `owner` is a "module class". I'm not exactly sure what that means, probably just that technically behind every singleton object there is also a class that is instantiated once.

So the following seems to work:

```
object TestDiscoverParent extends App {
  import scala.reflect.runtime.{currentMirror => cm, universe => ru}
  val theChildType = ru.typeOf[TheParent.TheChild]
  val theChildOwner = theChildType.typeSymbol.owner
  println(theChildOwner)
  require(theChildOwner.isModuleClass)
  val theParentModuleClass = theChildOwner.asClass
  val theParentModuleSymbol = theParentModuleClass.module.asModule
  val theParentRef = cm.reflectModule(theParentModuleSymbol).instance
  println(theParentRef.isInstanceOf[TheMixin])
}
```

Comment: Yup, I had tried asClass.asModule and it was still throwing the exception, I did not realize at first that .asClass made the module field visible. As you point out this works: val theParentModuleSymbol = theChildOwner.asClass.module.asModule